# UWP MediaPlaybackList adding MediaSource working too slow

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have a problem with `MediaPlaybackList`, as used like the following:

```
playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
playbackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = true;
for (int i = 0; i < songs.Count();i++)
{    
    var song = songs.ElementAt(i);    
    var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(
        await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(song.File));
    source.CustomProperties[TrackIdKey] = null;
    source.CustomProperties[TitleKey] = song.Title;
    source.CustomProperties[AlbumArtKey] = song.AlbumArtUri;
    source.CustomProperties[AuthorKey] = song.Author;
    source.CustomProperties[TrackNumber] = (uint)(i+1);
    playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));
}
```

When I try to add `MediaSource` to my playlist it takes too much time. 700 songs takes about 3 minutes to start playing. Maybe there is another way to add `MediaSource` to `MediaPlaybackList` which works faster?

Comment: I found in the [Background audio sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/17ab5a17cec10f3be56d7760035c80e616f40d8c/Samples/BackgroundAudio), it use `var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(song.MediaUri);` to get the songs.

Comment: I'm using this example, but in this example audio source in package, not in  external drive

Answer (score 5):

Use a IRandomAccessStreamReference.
That way it only has to load the file when it gets to the Item which is significantly faster.

You will have to write your own abstraction class though.
Might look a little like this:

```
public class MyStreamReference : IRandomAccessStreamReference
{
    private string path;

    public MyStreamReference(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType> OpenReadAsync()
        => Open().AsAsyncOperation();

    // private async helper task that is necessary if you need to use await.
    private async Task<IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType> Open()
        => await (await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path)).OpenReadAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would set PlaybackSource of the MediaElement before you get any files, and then I would just spin up a task to handle the loading on another thread.

This way, playback of the first file will start (or can be started) as soon as that one file is loaded, which was less than a second in my tests.

```
var playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
playbackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = true;
mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(playbackList);

await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < songs.Count(); i++)
    {
        var song = songs.ElementAt(i);

        var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(song.File));
        source.CustomProperties["TrackIdKey"] = null;
        source.CustomProperties["TitleKey"] = song.Title;
        source.CustomProperties["AlbumArtKey"] = song.AlbumArtUri;
        source.CustomProperties["AuthorKey"] = song.Author;
        source.CustomProperties["TrackNumber"] = (uint)(i + 1);
        playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));
        Debug.WriteLine($"[{i}] {song.Title} added to playlist");
    }
});
```

As a side project I adapted this slightly to load and play all of the tracks from a removable drive. The first part of the code gets the files from the drive, filters them by subfolder and creates song objects.

The rest is the same, except for the slight amendment to retrieve the StorageFile from KnownFolders.RemovableStorage...

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
    var songs = new List<Song>();
    string root = $@"{Path.GetPathRoot(files.FirstOrDefault()?.Path)}Tracks\";
    foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        if (file.Path.StartsWith(root))
            songs.Add(new Song { File = file.Path, Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Path) });

    var playbackList = new MediaPlaybackList();
    playbackList.AutoRepeatEnabled = true;
    mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(playbackList);

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.Count(); i++)
        {
            var song = songs.ElementAt(i);
            var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.GetFileAsync(song.File));
            source.CustomProperties["TrackIdKey"] = null;
            source.CustomProperties["TitleKey"] = song.Title;
            source.CustomProperties["AlbumArtKey"] = song.AlbumArtUri;
            source.CustomProperties["AuthorKey"] = song.Author;
            source.CustomProperties["TrackNumber"] = (uint)(i + 1);
            playbackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{i}] {song.Title} added to playlist");
        }
    });
}
```